# How to play pokemon go without wifi, whit mobile data

Tags: pokemon-go

Hi my phone was damaged and since then the wifi doesnt turn on, but the gps seem to work well but I still get this error "gps signal not found" in pokeemon go.my mobile data works great so I don't know whats the use of wifi..... please help

Comment: This is my favourite question of all questions I have seen

Comment: I don't want to edit it

Answer (score 1):

You are focusing on the wrong problem. Pokémon Go doesn't care if you're on Wifi or mobile data. As long as you're connected to the internet, the game can connect to Niantic's servers and you can play.

The actual problem is that the game somehow can't determine your current location using GPS, which is likely because your phone got damaged. Pokémon Go heavily relies on GPS, so playing without it is not an option.

You can choose to either:

- Get your phone repaired. Without GPS, you can't play the game at all.

or

- Buy a new phone. If the repairs are too expensive, it might be cheaper to just buy a new phone.

There's also the option of using a GPS spoofer, but there's a chance you'll get banned for that, so I won't recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an android and you say you're GPS works,then set it on high accuracy.  Android Settings>location

Not sure about iPhone